# Why @ModelAttribute does not work like @RequestBody?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My goal is to set a POJO attribute with `form-data`. I have a generic POJO, and when I use `JSON` it works as expected, so I am not sure `form-data` behave differently.

e.g

The POJO

```
public class Account_Info {
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String firstName;

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }
}
```

I wish to send a form data with "name" as key.

```
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("name", "a");
```

My expected result is: The POJO's attribute of `firstName` will have a value of `a`.

My actual result is: The POJO's attribute of `firstName` is null.

What I did:

1. I created a Account_InfoDto.

```
public class Account_InfoDto {
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String firstName;

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }
}
```

2. I created a controller

**with `@RequestBody`**

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/account_info")
  public Account_InfoDto postAccount_Info(@RequestBody Account_InfoDto account_info) {
    return account_info;
  }
```

**with `@ModelAttribute`**

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/account_info", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
  public Account_InfoDto postAccount_Info(@ModelAttribute Account_InfoDto account_info) {
    return account_info;
  }
```

3. Send a request to POST /account_info

with `JSON`

```
{
  "name": "a"
}
```

The actual response is:

```
{
  "name": "a"
}
```

**with `form-data`**

```
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("name", "a");
```

The actual result is:

```
{
  "name": null
}
```

Comment: Your form contains a parameter called `name`. What field of your `Account_InfoDto` class do you think that should be mapped to? Why do you think so?

Comment: @kidfrom also add the getter methods in your pojo

Comment: @kidfrom add setter methods for firstName field in your pojo

Comment: @EmmanuelOgoma it turns out you don't need annotation. It's as simple as `get...` and `set...`. e.g. `getFirstName` will return `{'firstName': 'value'}` and vice versa. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`@ModelAttribute` is used with view templates such as thymeleaf, and `@RequestBody` is used when you expect json payload,`@JsonProperty` is for mapping, it is not needed for formdata  . Since you are using formdata via ajax, you do not need any annotation on your payload. the following code

```
@PostMapping(value = "/account_info")
public Account_InfoDto postAccount_Info(@RequestBody Account_InfoDto account_info) {
return account_info;
}
```

should be

```
@PostMapping(value = "/account_info")
public Account_InfoDto postAccount_Info(Account_InfoDto account_info) {
return account_info;
}
```

also your request should be

```
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("firstName", "a");
```

for your DTO also include setters and getters

```
public class Account_InfoDto {
@JsonProperty("name")
private String firstName;

public String getFirstName() {
   return firstName;
 }
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
   this.firstName=firstName;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your second snippet is equivalent to theirs with `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `@ModelAttributte`  from the docs , Annotation that binds a method parameter or method return value to a named model attribute, exposed to a web view. Supported for controller classes with `@RequestMapping` methods.

Comment: Spring MVC, by default, handles `RequestMapping` method parameters that aren't annotated the same as if they were annotated with `@ModelAttribute`. So with or without it, it's the same behavior.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i think the edited answer now addresses whatever he had asked

Comment: Your suggestion to remove the `@ModelAttribute` is still unnecessary (and potentially misleading). That is not part of the problem.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis tell me where you will  use`@ModelAttribute` when handling ajax requests

Comment: Where you will _what_? Please rephrase that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis also check comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717177/ajax-call-param-with-modelattribute-in-spring

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java#L654) the source code that handles `@ModelAttribute`. You'll notice the first `ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor` on line 654 that passes `false`, requiring the `@ModelAttribute` annotation. Then **another** `ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor` is registered on line 686 that passes `true`, ie. doesn't need the annotation. They're handled the same way.

Comment: What does ajax have to do with anything? In the end, it's an HTTP request with content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @EmmanuelOgoma I checked it, and it is true that I don't need `@ModelAttribute` to handle `form-data`. I use JavaScript Fetch API. I have not test it with Ajax.

Comment: @EmmanuelOgoma could you please suggest using `setters` and `getters` in your answer, I use your solution from the comment you sent to me, I will mark it as answer today.

Comment: @kidfrom I have added the getters and setters